# double integrals with a bar

Tags: stacking-symbols

I usually use `\fint` to denote normalized integration. I would like to produce the same slanted line across a double integral `\iint`. The command `\fiint` does not seem to exist. How can I get this notation for normalized double integrals?

Comment: In contemporary mathematics, the use of double integrals is often considered to be old-fashioned. Aesthetically, it would be rather ugly, in my opinion.

Comment: Can you provide a pointer to `\fint`?  I don't know what the symbol looks like, or what package provides it.

Comment: the package ofr \fint is esint

Answer (score 2):

Using [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), [esint](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/esint) and [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) packages, you can declare the `\fiint` math operator in your preample, as: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\fiint}{\ensuremath{\iint\text{\kern-1.36em{\raisebox{5.87pt}{\rotatebox{-93}{$\setminus$}}}}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing (stealing?!) some code from the posting [The Principal Value Integral symbol](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-prinvalint), here are suggested versions of `\dashiint` and `ddashiint`; the former has a single horizontal bar going through the double-integral symbol, and the latter has a double horizontal bar. The following screenshot shows the symbols in display style and text (aka inline-math) style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \iint macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox and \raisebox macros
\def\Xint#1{\mathchoice
   {\XXint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
   {\XXint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
   {\XXint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
   {\XXint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
   \!\iint}
\def\XXint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\iint}$}
     \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$}}\kern-.51\wd0}}
     
\def\longminus{\raisebox{-2ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{20}{${-}\mkern-3.5mu{-}$}}}
\def\longequal{\raisebox{-2ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{20}{${=}\mkern-3.5mu{=}$}}}  
\def\dashiint{\Xint\longminus}
\def\ddashiint{\Xint\longequal}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\dashiint\ddashiint$
$\dashiint\ddashiint$
\end{document}
```